# Wiring a 220 outlet- can I use a 15 amp outlet with my 20 amp breaker? Or should I get a replacement 15 amp breaker?

Tags: receptacle, circuit-breaker, 240v

I'm trying to wire an outlet for my lathe.  The manufacturer recommends a 15 amp breaker. I am planning to run 10 gauge wire approximately 25' to the outlet where I can plug in my lathe. The motor is rated at 8 amps.  I currently have an empty 20 amp breaker for 220 in my box. Here are a few pics of what I'm thinking of using.

The first is the plug for the lathe:

[image: lathe controller and plug]

---

The second is the motor specs of the lathe:

[image: motor specs]

---

Would the following 20 amp outlet work for this?

[image: 20A outlet]

I've wired 110 but never 220. Also BTW it has a phase converter allowing it to run off 1 phase.

Answer (score 7):

You may know that on 120V circuits, you are allowed to use 15A receptacles on a 20A circuit.  This is a special exception that only applies to 15A receptacles only on 20A circuits.

*The Code says nothing about voltage.*. You can use exactly the same exception on a 240V 20A circuit. You are free to use 15A or 20A receptacles (NEMA 6-15 or 6-20).

If you use a 20A receptacle (NEMA 6-20), the 15A plug will fit in it just fine.  They are keyed to do that.   (Just the same way as 120V NEMA 5-20 sockets will accept the common NEMA 5-15 plugs.)

There is only one gotcha: if there is only one socket in the whole circuit, the socket size must match the breaker size.  So if you use a NEMA 6-15 on your 20A circuit, make sure it's the usual twin-socket receptacle, don't use a one-eye.

Comment: Hey thanks! That clears things up. Would this outlet be appropriate to match? It's a 20 amp, just has an extra T in it, I'm guessing to designate that its 20 amp?https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-20-Amp-Commercial-Grade-Double-Pole-Single-Outlet-White-R52-05821-0WS/100356999?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal2_rr-_-301207379-_-100356999-_-N

Comment: The T allows it to take both 15A and 20A plugs.

Comment: @BaceJuex yes, that will be fine, just make sure it's on a 20A breaker.  They also make those in duplex if you want two sockets.

Answer (score 1):

You may be close on the actual power needed if you reduce down to 15 amp protection. the motor is 8 amp 3 phase so if using single phase 240 to power the inverter 1.73 is the factor plus the losses of the inverter and the control starter , work light. since lathes are not a continuous duty device it may work but will be close. I would want to use a 20 amp outlet and keep the 20 amp breaker.

Comment: Thanks all, very helpful, just had to re read a couple times. I think I'll go with the 20 amp receptacle.